# Randomize qualitative variables

Tags: java

i need to randomize a "race" variable subject to ratio   white:black:Asian  e.g.  2:1:1

My program creates new people(objects) and i wish to randomize their race

```
//CONSTRUCTOR

public people() {
    race = raceGenerator();
}

public String raceGen() {
    String info;
    double probAllocation = Math.random();
    if (probAllocation < 0.5) {
        info = White;
    } else if (0.5 < probAllocation < 0.75) {
        info = Black;
    } else {
        info = Asian;
    }
    return info;
}
```

The problem is in the line `else if  (0.5 < probAllocation < 0.75) {info = Black;}`

my IDE tells me i have `bad operand types`

what does this mean and if this wont work is there a better way to randomize qualitative variables?

Answer (score 4):

You can't chain comparison operators like in math.

The syntax is:

```
else if (0.5 < probAllocation && probAllocation < 0.75)
```

or rather, to avoid holes in your range:

```
else if (0.5 <= probAllocation && probAllocation < 0.75)
```

or even simply

```
else if (probAllocation < 0.75)
```

since every value less than 0.5 will be handled by the first `if`.

Also, variables start with a lower-case in Java, and constants are all upper-case. So the values should probably be BLACK, WHITE and ASIAN. And you should consider using enums rather than Strings for these values, to make your code clearer and safer.

Comment: FWIW, you can omit the `0.5 <= probAllocation` entirely, since this possibility is ruled out by the `else if`

Answer (score 0):

You need two tests...

```
if (0.5 < probAllocation && probAllocation < 0.75) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The code line `else if (0.5 < probAllocation < 0.75) {info = Black;}` is not written correctly. you should use conditional AND operator to test both condition.

   else if (0.5 < probAllocation && probAllocation < 0.75) {info = Black;}
2. To generate random number you can use Random class from java.util package.

   Random randomGenerator = new Random();

   int rInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);   //This will generate the random number between 0 and 10.